# Tooltip on scrollviewer in documentviewer in case of deferred scrolling

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, scrollviewer, documentviewer

I want to show the tooltip on my scrollviewer on page scrolling which shows the current page number in it which i asked here- [Tooltip on scrollviewer in documentviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759074/tooltip-on-scrollviewer-in-documentviewer).

I have implemented the answer after making some changes in the proposed solution but i face some problem. If i write this in my scroll_changed event `if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)` it works perfectly fine but if i have a deferred scrolling enabled on my custom document viewer, the popup(tooltip) never appears..:(

Is there any workaround for it??

Comment: Well, if you deferr scrolling you are not *really* scrolling, so the ScrollChanged event won't fire.

Comment: Scroll changed won't fire while you are moving but once you are done with scrolling at that time, ScrollChanged event did get fired but at that time MouseButtonState is Released.. and hence no popup..

Comment: Obviously that is the case, but you do not want to display it when scrolling is done anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that can't be done with deferred scrolling while moving but i want to show the popup atleast at the time when i am done with dragging of scrollbar.

Comment: Then do only check for mousedown if deferred scrolling is on?

Comment: You didn't get me. Let me put this way,  ScrollChanged event fires in following cases - 
1. During DocumentViewer intialization.
2. On window resizing containing DocumentViewer.
3. And in case of deffered scrolling, when i release the scrollbar. I just want to show the popup for my 3rd case only and not for the first two cases.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated..